# Android Studio - "MakeProject" отрабатывает, но кнопка RUN не активна

Tags: android-studio

Помогите, пожалуйста, я пытаюсь запустить учебный проект из обучающего курса, у меня при нажатии на "MakeProject"  graddle отрабатывает, никаких ошибок не пишет, но кнопка run не становится активной. ПОдозреваю, что при сборке возникают какие-то ошибки, которые просто  не отображаются в окне Build, но где ещё посмотреть - я не знаю...
Что можно сделать, чтобы выяснить, в чём проблема?

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта. Покажите, как Вы создаете проект.

Answer (score 1):

Как выяснилось, проблема была в устаревшей версии appcompat в файле Build.gradle. Я просто добавила в конце плюсик:
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'